# PHP $stmt->bind_param() Number of variables doesn't match

Tags: php, sql

For some unknown reason my code doesn't seem to be working. I have checked all over google, but no one else seems to have the same problem. Could it be a bug with PHP?

The error I get:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/a9684274/public_html/system/db.php on line 102
```

The Code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='?'")
$name = "Vilsol";
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the single quotes `'`:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?")
```

In your code they will just be interpreted as a string value and not as a parametrizable value.